# White space popup and it increases if I add more text? see image

Tags: html, css, popup

I'm trying to learn Css from Udemy and I got stuck on this problem.
I asked there but I didn't get an answer yet..
Is there any way to get rid of that white space down there?
If I delete text, it disappear gradually and the same if I add text.
Can anyone help me? Thanks

[popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERSqm.jpg)

```css
.popup {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba($color-black, 0.8);
  z-index: 9999;

  &__content {
    @include absCenter;

    width: 75%;
    background-color: $color-white;
    box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba($color-black, 0.2);
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  &__left {
    width: 33.333333%;
    display: table-cell;
  }

  &__right {
    width: 66.6666667%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 3rem 5rem;
  }

  &__img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  &__text {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
    <div class="popup__content">
      <div class="popup__left">
        <img src="img/nat-8.jpg" alt="Tour photo" class="popup__img">
        <img src="img/nat-9.jpg" alt="Tour photo" class="popup__img">
      </div>
      <div class="popup__right">
        <h2 class="heading-secondary u-margin-bottom-small">Start booking now</h2>
        <h3 class="heading-tertiary u-margin-bottom-small">Important &ndash; Please read these term before booking</h3>
        <p class="popup__text">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error laudantium sed nulla
          inventore dignissimos facilis excepturi rerum animi eius recusandae? Magni, saepe quo commodi sapiente maxime
          magnam earum quidem ipsa? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, tempore architecto.
          Alias atque facilis nemo asperiores, sint officiis similique sequi doloribus nisi, fugiat earum. Sequi nisi
          quidem mollitia error provident. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi aspernatur
          itaque omnis aut perferendis reprehenderit, nisi vero quis consectetur repellat asperiores et, natus eligendi
          deserunt eveniet nobis laboriosam quo minus? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni,
          minus tenetur reiciendis nihil vitae neque quas consequatur totam itaque minima rerum, quam aspernatur
          dignissimos ducimus atque accusamus recusandae nesciunt cum?
        
        </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn--green">Book now
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Add display:block property to your image

Comment: It is already added for both images, for the left side &__img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;

Comment: Check from where the white space is coming.Its from image or popup left container?

Comment: and also if I reduce or increase the size of the browser there will be more or less blank space. Maybe is this a problem with responsive web design?

Comment: Yes, it comes from the popup__left. or is it from the image? the top image is: 360x239 and the bottom one is:360:247